# Xcode Instruments: Making sense of Zombies

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on a project that contains a framework I built. At runtime I'm receiving a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1` in my framework. I am usually able to immediately tell what in my code is causing this error, but at this moment in time it escapes me. I have been reading about how to debug this issue in Xcode and everyone seems to suggest using the Zombie tool in Instruments. I have followed the steps:

1. In my app project I went to Edit Scheme and enables zombie objects
2. I went to Xcode -> Developer Tools -> Instruments -> and selected "Zombies" (Interesting: it seems to open "Allocations". Confusing. [thanks Apple]).
3. In Zombies I selected my iPad in the upper left and choose the application.
4. I `COMMAND`+`R` to run my app and I pressed the `RECORD` button in Zombies. It starts to collect data.

[image]

What is displayed to me are some pink lines that seem to indicate trouble. Along with a whole bunch of gibberish such as `Malloc 4.00 KiB` and the like.

This makes no sense. There is nothing I can see that points out to me why something in my framework/project was deallocated.

How do I find the issue as to why my application is crashing with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1` with the information provided by Zombies?

Comment: I don't see anything in what you've written that would make me assume it's a zombie problem.  Do you have a stack trace or a debug console message from the crash?

Comment: (As a comment on your specific questions, there's nothing suspicious in the pink lines; if you hit a zombie in Instruments when it's set up to detect them it will tell you explicitly.)

Comment: Hello Phillip. There is a call stack, but the method where the EXC_BAD_ACCESS is crashing is not in that stack. Infact, that method should never be called. But it is.

Comment: "if you hit a zombie in Instruments...". How do I know a Zombie in Zombies when I see one?